# Inner join with postgres array field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

We have a CMS using rails,react and postgresql. We have pages and pieces stored in our table.
Each page consist of a set of pieces (An array field).

We have pieces that can be used across multiple pages.

[image]

Let's say we are rendering page_id `50806`. our react front end requires data in the following format.

```
pieces: [
 {id: B1fu5jthb, included_on_pages: [50808, 50806]},
 {id: BJTNssF2Z, included_on_pages: [50808]}
]
```

So currently, to find `included_on_pages`, i am writing one query to fetch all the pieces of the page and then looping over each piece to find pages where the particular piece is included.

**(Basically N+1 queries.)**

`select pieces from  page_pieces where page_id = 50806`

`Looping over each piece`

`select page_id from  page_pieces where  'B1fu5jthb' = any(page_pieces.pieces);`

So my question,
Instead of looping over each piece and find which pages its included, can we write a single `join statements` to fetch all the pieces and their `included_on_pages`

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of unnesting, `ANY` comparison and array aggregation should work:

```
with
  pcs as (select unnest(pieces) as id from page_pieces where page_id = 50806)
select id, array_agg(page_id) as included_on_pages
from pcs inner join page_pieces on id = any(pieces)
group by id;
```

[See it on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3655a/1/0)